# Will a re-render of App() automatically re-render screens in navigation?

Tags: react-native

In the code below, if setStateVar is called but it doesn't affect which screens are displayed by the stacknavigator, will the displayed screen re-render or not? And if yes, is there a way to change this?

```
function App() {
  const {stateVar, setStateVar} = useContext(VarContext);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {stateVar == null ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown:false}} name="LoadingScreen" component={LoadingScreen} />
          </>
        )  :  (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen} />
          </>
        
        ) 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it will. Even if you wrapped your components in `React.memo()`, if they use that context somewhere in their graph, they will rerender at the highest graph node that uses said context.